# Pre requisite before get the range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Just curious whether it possible to add some value to a cell before get the SUM of a range.

E.g. As per below total should be 118

[image]

[image]

Comment: @BigBen, My bad total should be `118`, Updated accordingly

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCnNn.png. May need confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter (can't recall for previous versions of Excel).

Comment: @BigBen Yeah I get `12` for the above

Comment: Ok, then confirm the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter.

Comment: cool, this is the one `{=SUM(A2:A5+2)}`. It shows the one you defined after press enter. Just curious why

Comment: This is necessary for previous versions of Excel since it is an array formula. In newer versions, formulas are evaluated in an array context by default, so Control+Shift+Enter is not necessary. Note that Excel adds the `{}` automatically for you.

Comment: @BigBen I was trying to extend above to this `=SUMIF(SUM(2+A2:A5),">20")` but it's complaining about the formula.

Comment: `SUMIF` works with ranges. You're passing it a number as the first argument.

Comment: @BigBen Ok. What I after there was, do this `SUM(2+A2:A5)` first and then apply `SUMIF ` for the same range. More like apply previous `SUM ` while doing the `SUMIF ` range. Which looks like not acceptable here.

Comment: Try `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A5+2>20))`.

Comment: @BigBen Not quite. I get result as `3 ` for the sample data in the question, but expected is `84 `

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5>20)*(A2:A5+2))`

Answer (score 2):

Just do `=SUM(2+range)`

For example:

[image]

Comment: In my case still need to add `{ } ` either side.

Comment: @SMPH - Can you not do: `=SUM(2*COUNT(D1:D4),D1:D4)` or  `=SUM(2*ROWS(D1:D4),D1:D4)`? It is effectively the same as EDS's but aggregates everything inside of the SUM. In any case, the formula from EDS and your formula work fine on my Excel365 instance and I don't have access to older versions to test.